# How do I add a flash mp3 player to my webpage using dreamweaver

Tags: flash, mp3, dreamweaver

I want embed a little flash mp3 player in a webpage page using Dreamweaver cs3. This is the little player with the stop and pause buttons.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have DreamWeaver CS3, and you have a Flash file locally called

mp3player.swf within the same folder as your html file

Click **Insert** -> **Media** -> **Flash**

Make sure when you get your file you use the option relative to Document

Insert a Title say Mp3 Player

you will get the following placed in your html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','550','height','400','title','Mp3 Player','src','file:///Macintosh HD/Users/phwd/Desktop/mp3player','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','file:///Macintosh HD/Users/phwd/Desktop/mp3player' ); //end AC code
</script><noscript><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="550" height="400" title="Mp3 Player">
    <param name="movie" value="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/phwd/Desktop/mp3player.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/phwd/Desktop/mp3player.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="400"></embed>
  </object></noscript>
```

**NOTE** that I have

**file:///Macintosh HD/Users/phwd/Desktop/mp3player**

and

**file:///Macintosh HD/Users/phwd/Desktop/mp3player.swf**

in your case it will be

mp3player and mp3player.swf

Answer (score 2):

> I want embed a little flash mp3 player in a webpage page using Dreamweaver cs3. This is the little player with the stop and pause buttons.

Do you have Flash? Has the flash mp3 player been created? Are you planning to have the flash swf file on the same server or it's remote?

Is your question:

- I don't know how to make a flash mp3 player?
- I don't know how to embed a flash mp3 player?

Please clarify.